# Outer AngularJS directive doesn't build inner directive correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Using AngularJS 1.0.8, I'm trying to create some reusable directives to create a situation where a web developer can code a single "top-level" directive with a number of attributes, and this directive, in turn, has a template containing other directives, which themselves might contain other directives etc.

The problem I'm having is making the "inner" templates aware of the top level attributes. I thought this would be a universal problem, but it didn't look, from my research, that anyone else was asking this.

I created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3wq6F1Z3AppOstqDkKl?p=preview) to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="outerInnerDirectivesApp">
<head>
    <title>Outer/Inner Directives</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Single level directive follows:</div>
<single-level-directive single-level-id="single123"></single-level-directive>
<div>Outer/inner directive follows (Expecting "outer123"):</div>
<outer-directive outer-id="outer123"></outer-directive>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Plunker,

1. single-level-directive works and is, I think, a standard way to display data.
2. outer-directive and inner-directive aren't working.

What I expected to happen with these was

(i) outerDirective compiles/links to produce the html

```
<inner-directive inner-id="outer123"></inner-directive>
```

and then

(ii) innerDirective compiles/links to produce html

```
<div>outer123</div>
```

But at step (ii) I get

```
<inner-directive inner-id="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
   <div class="ng-binding"></div>
</inner-directive>
```

so an empty div is generated by innerDirective.

In fact, if I change outer-template.html to be

```
<div>{{outerId}}<div>
```

then the value displays correctly, so it looks like scope.outerId is available at the correct point, but Angular isn't happy about me trying to use it in the way I am.

Is this a reasonable thing to expect Angular to do? If so, what am I missing? If not, then what do you think would be a sensible alternative way to build up more complex screens from simple sets of directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to design directives with isolated scope, I would suggest using the isolated scope to define the type of attribute you want to use:

```
outerInnerApp.directive("outerDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      outerId: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    templateUrl: "outer-template.html"
  };
});
outerInnerApp.directive("innerDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      innerId: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    templateUrl: "inner-template.html"
  };
});
```

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hS8rPGVQBJ3UmDZgg2o8?p=preview).

Your outer directive is using the value that is defined in the attribute.  So, to pass the value into the isolated scope, we can use `@`.  The inner scope is then binding a variable through.  So, we can use `=` to set up a bound attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Davin. That's exactly what I needed. In fact your answer showed up a big gap in my understanding, which was very useful to fill!

Comment: For the benefit of others I'll explain my original knowledge gap below (correct me if I'm wrong, anyone).

The outerId: '@' bit is fine. It's looking for an attribute in the HTML ...outer-id="value"... or ...outer-id={{interpolatedValue}} 

What I'd not appreciated, however, was that

innerId: '='

adds a level of indirection. It's looking in the HTML for ...inner-id='propertyName' and will then look up the value of $parentScope.propertyName to arrive at the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Had some more thoughts about this. Having used AngularJS a bit more, I'm not sure that I want to bind to the scope (using the "="). In fact, I can get the original Plunkr to work by making these changes:

```
outerInnerApp.directive("outerDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
        //add outerId here
        outerId: "@"
        },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //remove scope assignment here
        //scope.outerId = attrs.outerId;
    },
    templateUrl: "outer-template.html"
    };
});
outerInnerApp.directive("innerDirective", function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        //add innerId here
        innerId: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //remove scope assignment here
        //scope.innerId = attrs.innerId;
    },
    templateUrl: "inner-template.html"
    };
});
```

What I don't understand at the moment is why there is a different between, say,

```
innerId:"@"
```

and setting the value of scope in the link function

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.innerId = attrs.innerId;
}
```

When I find out why it behaves differently I'll post back.

Comment: You might want to post this as its own question, not as an answer to a question that's already been answered and accepted.